# LDAP Authentication without Login credentials VB6

Tags: vb6, active-directory, ldap, vb.net-2010

I have created a VB6 program which will user LDAP authentication. But the same authentication is working in server using LDP.exe which allow user both, with login credentials and also without credentials. But when I try in client machine (XP) it says:

> Domain does not exist.

```
Dim objGroup As IADsGroup
Dim strDN As String
Dim adsSystemInfo As IADsADSystemInfo
strDN = "CN=Users,dc=DomainName,dc=Net"
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)
Set adsSystemInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
```

Comment: Are you running VB6 as an administrator and/or the compiled app as an administrator?

Comment: With Administrator Permissions  using VB6 (In XP)

Answer (score 0):

Reference the activeds.tlb in your project. Usage:

```
 With New ADSystemInfo
  MsgBox ("Computer Name: " & .ComputerName)
  MsgBox ("User Name: " & .UserName)
 End With
```

You can also use ADO to query LDAP objects, such as:

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim oField As ADODB.Field
Dim iP As IADs

oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
oConn.CursorLocation = adUseNone
oConn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

oRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
oRS.Open "Select * from 'LDAP://domain'", oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Set iP = GetObject(oRS(0).Value)

While Not oRS.EOF
 For Each oField In oRS.Fields
  List1.AddItem oField.Name & " / " & oField.Value
 Next

 oRS.MoveNext
Wend

oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
```

Comment: But why the above code is not working? Is it due to OS or application level